# conan/cmake can't see llvm linker when cross-compiling from macOS (arm64) to Windows (x86_x64)

Tags: cmake, llvm, cross-compiling, conan

I'm trying to cross-compile simple "hello world" test program on mac machine targeting Windows.

### Configuration

- `conan 2.1`
- `cmake 3.28.3`
- `llvm clang 17.0.6`
  All installed using `homebrew`.

When I'm cross-compiling 'manually' it works without errors or warnings. It "only" fails for conan/cmake.

### Manual steps that work

```bash
# To use brew llvm instead of AppleClang
export LLVM_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm
export PATH="$LLVM_DIR/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L$LLVM_DIR/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$LLVM_DIR/include"
export CC=$LLVM_DIR/bin/clang
export CXX=$LLVM_DIR/bin/clang++

# For cross compilation (Windows):
export SDK_DIR=/Users/pawel/SDKs
export MSVC_DIR=$SDK_DIR/MSVC/14.39.33519
export WIN_INC_DIR=$SDK_DIR/Win/10/Include/10.0.22621.0
export WIN_LIB_DIR=$SDK_DIR/Win/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0

# Compile
clang++ \
-I$MSVC_DIR/include \
-L$MSVC_DIR/lib/x64 \
-I$WIN_INC_DIR/ucrt \
-L$WIN_LIB_DIR/ucrt/x64 \
-L$WIN_LIB_DIR/um/x64 \
-fuse-ld=lld-link \
-lmsvcrt \
-lucrt \
-lvcruntime \
-o hello.exe \
-target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc \
-g \
-O0 \
hello.cpp
```

### Failing conan/cmake

I'll provide the content of all relevant files below, but first commands I've used:

```bash
# conan using host/build pair:
conan install . \
--output-folder=cmake-build-win-debug \
--profile:host=host-windows-llvm-x64-debug \
--profile:build=build-mac-llvm-x64-debug

# cmake using preset generated by conan (it does exist)
cmake --preset windows-debug
```

`coanfile.py`

```py
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMakeDeps

class PackageConan(ConanFile):
    settings = 'os', 'build_type', 'compiler', 'arch'
    options = {'target_os': ['Windows', 'Macos']}

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.presets_prefix = f'{self.options.target_os}'.lower()
        tc.generate()
        
        cmake_deps = CMakeDeps(self)
        cmake_deps.generate()
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(hello CXX)

# Specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
```

#### Conan profiles

`default-llvm`

```ini
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=clang
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=17
os=Macos

[buildenv]
CC=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang
CXX=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
```

`build-mac-llvm-x64-debug`

```ini
include(default-llvm)

[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Debug

[buildenv]
CXXFLAGS=-g -O0
```

`host-windows-llvm-x64-debug`

```ini
include(default-llvm)

[settings]
os=Windows
arch=x86_64
build_type=Debug

[options]
target_os=Windows

[conf]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja

[buildenv]
CXXFLAGS=-g -O0
LDFLAGS=-fuse-ld=lld-link -L/Users/pawel/SDKs/MSVC/14.39.33519/lib/x64 -L/Users/pawel/SDKs/Win/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/x64 -L/Users/pawel/SDKs/Win/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64
PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

### Error message

```
clang++: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld-link'
```

Comment: This looks like a valid bug report for https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: It could be related to this feature request https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/15451, the issue seems to be custom linker paths cannot be specified, only compiler executables, so it seems a gap for cross-build when linker needs customization too.